Gradle can't find querydsl plugin
plugins {
 id "org.springframework.boot" version "3.3.2"
 id "io.spring.dependency-management" version "1.1.6"
 id "io.freefair.lombok" version "8.7.1"
 id "com.ewerk.gradle.plugins.querydsl" version "1.0.10"
 id 'java'
}

Plugin [id: 'com.ewerk.gradle.plugins.querydsl', version: '1.0.10'] was not found in any of the following sources:

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.
BUILD FAILED in 3s

I tried not specifying a version, but it didn't work that way either. I must have googled badly, because I couldn't find a solution.

Generic answer;
Make sure you have appropriate sources for your dependency repositories set, example (where QueryDSL is located in Maven repositories):
repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
}

It depends where your repository is stored.
Edit: Digging a bit deeper, seems like you have incorrect or some 3rd party QueryDSL dependencies, looks like the original dependencies are:
implementation "com.querydsl:querydsl-jpa:${querydslVersion}:jakarta"
annotationProcessor "com.querydsl:querydsl-apt:${querydslVersion}:jakarta"
annotationProcessor "jakarta.persistence:jakarta.persistence-api"
annotationProcessor "jakarta.annotation:jakarta.annotation-api"

with specified querydsl version:
ext {
    querydslVersion = '5.0.0'
}

source: Spring Boot 3 Integrate QueryDsl with Gradle

I've specified these repositories, but still nothing

Use:
    implementation "com.querydsl:querydsl-jpa"
    annotationProcessor 'com.querydsl:querydsl-apt'

